# How did the term PAN PAN originate?

Tags: aviation-history

Where did the phrase "pan-pan", used when declaring an emergency, originate?

Answer (score 12):

[Wikipedia has an un-cited reference to the etymology being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-pan)

> As with mayday (from venez m'aider, "come help me"), the urgency
>   signal pan-pan derives from French. In French, a panne ([pan], "pahn")
>   is a breakdown, such as a mechanical failure. In English, it is also
>   sometimes[vague] pronounced as /pæn/ ("pan").

[This article supports that history](http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/internet/broadband/history-of-the-distress-signal-pan-pan-sos-mayday-communications-11364164714836) (and has many of the other emergency phrase histories as well).

Comment: The last link sends to an ads page now.